# How to make all forms in a project as mdi child of mdi form.

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

In my winforms I have mdi form. Here I want to make all forms as child of mdi parent.

My forms structure are like this.

```
MainForm (Mdi parent)
FrmEmployeeDetails(child of MainForm)
FrmNewEmployeeDetails(child of FrmEmployeeDetails)
```

When I execute the project.form `NewEmployeeDetails` is opening outside the MainForm.

For `FrmEmployeeDetails` I coded like this.

```
FrmEmployeeDetails EmployeeDetails= new FrmEmployeeDetails();
EmployeeDetails.MDIparent=this;
EmployeeDetails.show();
```

`FrmNewEmployeeDetails` is child form of `FrmEmployeeDetails`.

For the form `FrmEmployeeDetails` I am creating `NewEmployeeDetails` as like this.

```
FrmNewEmployeeDetails newemployeedetails = new FrmNewEmployeeDetails();
newemployeedetails.show();
```

> How can I make `FrmNewEmployeeDetails`
>   as mdi child of `MainForm`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you should make this

```
FrmNewEmployeeDetails newemployeedetails = new FrmNewEmployeeDetails();
// Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
newemployeedetails.MdiParent = this;
// Display the new form.
newemployeedetails.Show();
```

Comment: i have done this in form. FrmEmployeeDetails.but how can i make the MainForm  as mdi parent of FrmNewEmployeeDetails.

Comment: create the FrmEmployeeDetails and mark it as MainForm 's son and then create FrmNewEmployeeDetails  and mark it as FrmEmployeeDetails 's son. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
EmployeeDetails.MDIparent=this;
```

to

```
EmployeeDetails.MDIparent=this.MdiParent;
```